# How can I print records with difference in maximum and minimum value greater than a certain threshold?

Tags: text-processing

I have data like this in two columns:

```
[id1] 09:51:07,175
[id1] 09:51:07,215
[id2] 10:09:47,550
[id2] 10:09:47,588
[id2] 10:09:47,942
[id2] 10:09:47,947
[id3] 10:05:25,945
[id3] 10:05:26,001
```

The first column is IDs and the other is time.
Now, I want to print IDs if the difference between their minimum and maximum times is greater than x.

If x = 100, the desired output would be:

```
id2
```

Because max(id2) = 10:09:47,947 and min(id2) = 10:09:47,550
and their difference is 397. If x=30, the desired output would be:

```
id1
id2
id3
```

because

```
max(id1) - min(id1) = 40
max(id2) - min(id2) = 397
max(id3) - min(id3) = 56
```

if x is 50 then output would be:

```
id2
id3
```

How can I approach this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make sure the example input is accurate. You left a comment suggesting that some lines have a totally different format and include the full date!

Comment: This question was crossposted with different phrasing and different format of input lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72571636/group-by-with-having-with-awk

Comment: date format thing can be ignored, we can only work on time. I've edited question accordingly

Comment: ok, I am new to this awk. I was asking without learning. I guess, I should learn, and try first with my full effort on weekend. Thanks for your support guys. Let the question remain as it is. I'll come back after learning a bit, then it would make much sense. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Is it possible to get the data in unix time? As stated, you'll end up with problems if you happen to have data that crosses over 23:59:59 to 00:00:01.

That would also simplify the answer, especially if you guarantee that the data is a time-series and doesn't need to be sorted. I'd loop through the list, storing the first incidence in one array and then just dumping all the remaining values in a second one. So you end up with something like:

start_values = [ id1: 16677, ... ] end_values = [ id1: 16680, ... ]

which would be your min and max values.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more a programming/algorithm question than a unix question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical job for `perl`:

```
perl -MList::Util=min,max -lsne '
  push @{$v{$1}}, $5 + 1000 * ($4 + 60 * ($3 + 60 * $2)) if
    m{^\[(.*)\] (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d),(\d+)$};
  END{
    for (keys %v) {
      print if max(@{$v{$_}}) - min(@{$v{$_}}) > $threshold
    }
  }' -- -threshold=100 < your-file
```

If could be made more efficient and less memory  at the expense of more complicated code hungry by computing the min and max as we read the lines rather than storing  all the values and calling `min()` and `max()` in the end. But unless the input is very large, it's not likely to make much difference.